# possible to use coalesce with pivot/count to map nulls to zeros in spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, null, pivot

In the course of learning pivotting in Spark Sql I found a simple example with count that 
resulted in rows with nulls.

From the spark shell, if you do this->

```
val visits = Seq(
  (0, "Warsaw", 2015),
  (1, "Warsaw", 2016),
  (2, "Boston", 2017)
).toDF("id", "city", "year")

val withNulls = visits.groupBy("city").pivot("year", Seq("2015", "2016", "2017")).count()
withNulls.show()
```

you get this output:

```
+------+----+----+----+
|  city|2015|2016|2017|
+------+----+----+----+
|Warsaw|   1|   1|null|
|Boston|null|null|   1|
+------+----+----+----+
```

I can convert the nulls to zeros with one more step with the 'na' function, like this:

```
val noNulls = withNulls .na.fill(0)
 noNulls.show()
```

And the result is what I want:

```
+------+----+----+----+
|  city|2015|2016|2017|
+------+----+----+----+
|Warsaw|   1|   1|   0|
|Boston|   0|   0|   1|
+------+----+----+----+
```

I'd assume it would be more efficient if I could do this in one step.  But I was not able to 
come up with a good one step solution.  Below is one failed attempt which left the nulls in place and changed my (valid) 1 counts to zeros (which is not at all correct!).

```
visits.groupBy("city").pivot("year", Seq("2015", "2016", "2017")).agg(expr("coalesce(count(),0)")).show()
```

Maybe one of the Spark Sql experts out there could clue me in on how to do this the right way ?  I'm pretty sure *coalesce* would be useful, but any one step solution, even without *coalesce*, would be most welcome !

**Update:**

I am going to accept Chandan's answer (thanks, Chandan !) and will conclude that the clearest and most efficient way to do this is with na.fill(0)

Looking deeper into  the accepted solution it seems to me that there would be an additional 
job kicked off to get the list of columns (in the form of one case statement per column) that is used by the select in 
that solution.

I verified this via the spark UI. When I executed this statement:

```
scala> val cols = visits.groupBy("city").pivot("year").count.columns.map(i => when(col(i).isNull,0).otherwise(col(i)).alias(i))
```

I saw statistics for an additional job in the UI.... which makes sense as there are two 'counts' in Chandan's solution, 
each of which is an action which would cause a job to be kicked off.  The other interesting thing I noted about the accepted 
solution is that the value of cols is a list of case statements, one per each column, and it is these case statements that 
actually apply the "if null->then zero" conversion logic.

```
cols: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(CASE WHEN (city IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE city END AS `city`, CASE WHEN (2015 IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 2015 END AS `2015`, CASE WHEN (2016 IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 2016 END AS `2016`, CASE WHEN (2017 IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE 2017 END AS `2017
```

Comment: `.na.fill(0)` is the way to go. There is really nothing to gain here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible inside agg api.

You can use the na.fill as you mentioned or please find the below approach.

```
visits.groupBy("city").pivot("year").count.select(visits.groupBy("city").pivot("year").count.columns.map(i => when(col(i).isNull,0).otherwise(col(i)).alias(i)):_*).show
```